# SQL Server TRY_CONVERT Not Working As Expected

Tags: sql-server

See the attached image - I can't figure out why TRY_CONVERT is returning `null`. I've posted the code here as well, but it's simply showing the original field, the field converted to datetime, and then a string (which is equal to the field - as I've shown in my case statement) being converted to a datetime. What gives?

```
select b.[Sent to Simon Mgmt for Signature], 
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, b.[Sent to simon mgmt for signature]) as CONVERTED_FIELD, 
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '05/27/2015') as CONVERTED_STR,
case when '05/27/2015' = b.[Sent to simon mgmt for signature] then 'EQUAL' else 'FALSE' end as ARE_VALUES_EQUAL from Opportunity a
left join ssle.dbo.LRA_Status b on Opportunity_Id__c = b.DealId
where Opportunity_Id__c = '20150424163443BAUN-9VVS5Q'
```

SQL Output

```
05/27/20﻿15 | NULL | 2015-05-27 00:00:00.000 | EQUAL
```

[image: sql output]

Comment: what is the datatype of [Sent to Simon Mgmt for Signature]

Comment: @SQLChao nvarchar(255) (set to 255 because it's part of a migration

Comment: Probably because you have an invalid date in your string column (why, oh why, are you storing dates in string columns?). This is how TRY_CONVERT() is advertised to work - return NULL if it comes across a value it can't convert. What I suspect is happening for this row is that there are trailing spaces or other non-printing characters in that row. Check DATALENGTH and/or loop through the characters and check the ASCII().

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is one of many date fields, none of the others are having problems with conversion. also, I chose 'TRY', because I can't really trust the source data

Comment: @AaronBertrand CONVERT gives me a 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' error

Comment: That's not a date column. That's a string column. There's a big difference. If you're only storing dates there, change it from the completely inappropriate `nvarchar(255)`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is a migration project, so I'm bringing everything in everything as text, and then converting into the proper formats in my staging table, where I store them as dates.

Comment: What does this yield? `SELECT RIGHT([Sent to Simon Mgmt for Signature], 1), ASCII(RIGHT([Sent to Simon Mgmt for Signature]), 1) FROM  ssle.dbo.LRA_Status WHERE b.DealId = '20150424163443BAUN-9VVS5Q';`

Comment: @AaronBertrand 5 and 53, respectively, so it looks like your hunch of non printing characters was correct. thanks!

Comment: And does the problem get fixed if you say `UPDATE ssle.dbo.LRA_Status SET [Sent to Simon Mgmt for Signature] = '05/27/2015' WHERE b.DealId = '20150424163443BAUN-9VVS5Q';`? If not, are you sure it's `nvarchar` and not `char` or `nchar`?

Comment: @logan_gabriel the ASCII value for 5 *is* 53 so I'm not sure what conclusion you are drawing from that?

Comment: Agree with @MartinSmith.  The last character is '5', and the ASCII code for 5 is 53.  However, the problem is likely an invalid character.  Please check `select datalength([Sent to Simon Mgmt for Signature])` to determine if there's any extra characters.  You should expect 20 (2x number of chars since it's nvarchar).

Comment: @ArinTaylor yes that date that is giving me problems is of length 22. thanks, looks like I'll run an update on any string where the length is not 20.